JDK Proxy Issue Spring Boot 3 Java 17
We have migrated our lambda function to JAVA 17 and Spring boot 3 from JAVA 11 and Spring boot 2.
Also we have multiple environment where we are testing the lambda function.
What we have observed is that the same migrated code is not having consistent behavior across all the lower environment and production environment.
The lambda function is working fine in few of the env and failing to load the context on few including production env.
Below is the error we have encountered in env where it is failing to instantiate :
"message":"\n\n***************************\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\n***************************\n\nDescription:\n\nThe bean 'BeanName' could not be injected because it is a JDK dynamic proxy\n\nThe bean is of type 'jdk.proxy2.$Proxy136' and implements:\n\tcom.......MarkerInterface\n\tcom.......NormalInterface\n\torg.springframework.aop.SpringProxy\n\torg.springframework.aop.framework.Advised\n\torg.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy\n\nExpected a bean of type 'com.......ClazzName' which implements:\n\tcom.......MarkerInterface\n\tcom......******.NoramlInterface\n\n\nAction:\n\nConsider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
We tried with enabling the CGLIB in this lambda function and it worked where it was failing.
Also compared the class loading information of the classes in both the env and they are absolutely same.
Also we are using @EnableCaching and not using @EnableAsync in our function.
Now the ask is why it is working on few env and breaking in other. The same code has been deployed to each environment (checked the code digest).
Also the all env are in same account AWS account.
Any debugging tips are well come to understand the issue.
